# Update columns in one data.frame using another dataframe with columns of the same name

Tags: r

I have a dataframe, D1, with these columns:

```
a b c
3 4 2
2 1 2
2 0 3
```

and another, D2, with these columns

```
b c
2 1
3 2
4 4
```

I want to build another dataframe with all D2 columns, and D1 columns that are not in D2. I mean, D3 would be this:

```
a b c
3 2 1
2 3 2
2 4 4
```

There are a lot of columns. Is it possible to build D3 without explicitly referencing them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `setdiff` to find the columns that are not in the second dataset

```
cbind(df1[setdiff(names(df1), names(df2))], df2)
```

Comment: Thank you! It's exactly what I wanted